# Mysql entity framework - Не удалось найти запрошенного поставщика данных

Tags: mysql, сервер, entity-framework, развертывание

Имеется Web API приложение использующее сервер баз данных MySQL. На девелоперской машине работает прекрасно. Перенёс приложение на сервер и после обращения к странице вылетает исключение:

```
{
    ClassName: "System.ArgumentException",
    Message: "Указанный поставщик хранилища не найден в конфигурации или недопустим.",
    Data: null,
    InnerException: - {
    ClassName: "System.ArgumentException",
    Message: "Не удалось найти запрошенного поставщика данных .Net Framework. Возможно он не установлен.",
    Data: null,
    InnerException: null,
    HelpURL: null,
    StackTraceString: " в System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)",
    RemoteStackTraceString: null,
    RemoteStackIndex: 0,
    ExceptionMethod: "8 GetFactory System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory GetFactory(System.String)",
    HResult: -2147024809,
    Source: "System.Data.Entity",
    WatsonBuckets: null,
    ParamName: null
    },
    HelpURL: null,
    StackTraceString: " в System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) в System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() в System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) в MMSBDWebApplication.Models.UserModel.Login(String login, String password) в MMSBDWebApplication.Controllers.v1.UserController.Test()",
    RemoteStackTraceString: null,
    RemoteStackIndex: 0,
    ExceptionMethod: "8 GetFactory System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory GetFactory(System.String)",
    HResult: -2147024809,
    Source: "System.Data.Entity",
    WatsonBuckets: null,
    ParamName: null
}
```

**Конфигурационный файл:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Дополнительные сведения о настройке приложения ASP.NET см. по адресу:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    Описание изменений web.config см. по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    Следующие атрибуты можно установить с помощью тега <httpRuntime>.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mmsbdEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DatabaseModel.DatabaseEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DatabaseModel.DatabaseEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DatabaseModel.DatabaseEntityModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=databaseserv0403!;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=mmsbd&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Структура файлов полностью идентичны, как на сервере так и на девелоперской машине. Все библиотеки на месте. В чём может быть еще проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил, установив [MySql Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)